# bash unzip retaining partial directory structure

Tags: bash, unzip

Clients submit large (1.5gigs, >10,000 files) zip file with their directory structure from clients OUTPUT directory.
I want to bash unzip to my INPUT directory, preserving their directory structure also, BUT NOT ENTIRE directory structure.

Example, if their zip file contains the files:

```
/home/base/data/output/able/file1.xml
/home/base/data/output/able/file2.xml
/home/base/data/output/able/file3.xml
/home/base/data/output/baker/file1.xml
/home/base/data/output/baker/file2.xml
/home/base/data/output/baker/file3.xml
/home/base/data/output/charlie/file1.xml
/home/base/data/output/charlie/file2.xml
/home/base/data/output/charlie/file3.xml
(this goes on for thousands of files in about a dozen unique directories)
```

I want to unzip them to my INPUT directory as below:

```
../input/able/file1.xml
../input/able/file2.xml
../input/able/file3.xml
../input/baker/file1.xml
../input/baker/file2.xml
../input/baker/file3.xml
../input/charlie/file1.xml
../input/charlie/file2.xml
../input/charlie/file3.xml
```

So far I tried:

```sh
unzip BIGFILE.zip   /output/   input   --(*) before and after /output/
```

which does unzip all xml files with the directory structure of `able/baker/charlie`, etc.
HOWEVER, it also unpacks the entire file structure BEFORE `/output`:

```
../input/home/base/data/output/able/file1.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/able/file2.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/able/file3.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/baker/file1.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/baker/file2.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/baker/file3.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/charlie/file1.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/charlie/file2.xml
../input/home/base/data/output/charile/file3.xml
```

Probably can't be done in a one liner, but haven't found any scripts that would read in the partial directory a couple thousand files, then unzip them to a specific directory.
Any thoughts?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/892099?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/518347

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). This page is dedicated to questions about software development.